# How i can get the variable data as string like a dd() function in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to get the request data but i cant get ip, fullUrl and others with all() method (this only print input values), but when i use "dd(request())" this show me all data (i need the data what is printed with dd method, but like a string to save, withour the exception who print this data). Im debbuging my app so i need to save every request data in a log file, something like:

`\Log::debug($request)`

So,

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```php
\Log::debug($request->toString());
```

or alternatively you can use

```php
\Log::debug((string) $request);
```

The Laravel Request object comes from [`Illuminate\Http\Request`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php) which extends [`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation`](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Request.php#L495) which exposes the following code:

```php
    public function __toString()
    {
        try {
            $content = $this->getContent();
        } catch (\LogicException $e) {
            return trigger_error($e, E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        $cookieHeader = '';
        $cookies = [];
        foreach ($this->cookies as $k => $v) {
            $cookies[] = $k.'='.$v;
        }
        if (!empty($cookies)) {
            $cookieHeader = 'Cookie: '.implode('; ', $cookies)."\r\n";
        }
        return
            sprintf('%s %s %s', $this->getMethod(), $this->getRequestUri(), $this->server->get('SERVER_PROTOCOL'))."\r\n".
            $this->headers.
            $cookieHeader."\r\n".
            $content;
    }
```

`__toString()` is considered a magic method in PHP.

> The `__toString()` method allows a class to decide how it will react
>   when it is treated like a string. For example, what echo $obj; will
>   print. This method must return a string, as otherwise a fatal
>   `E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR` level error is emitted.

You can read more about it in the official [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring).

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to store just what you want from request data if you don't need all of them, however for both cases you can take a look at [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)